# Given a set of numbers which return a response code, how can I find the algorithm used to produce the response?

Tags: hash, algorithm-design

I'm working on a problem where I provide an 8 digit integer and a 16 digit integer, then a 10 digit integer response is produced.

For example `12345678` and `1234123412341234` produces `138259849`

The same inputs always produce the same output.

Is it possible to find the algorithm used to calculate the response?

Comment: If you are able to ask as many times as possible like it is an Oracle, you can build a table. Game server hackers use this way and instead of generating the algorithm, most of the0 time they use a table representation of the function and it turns out it is faster than the original algorithm. Could you provide the source of the problem?

Comment: though the table is too big since $10^{24} \approx 2^{80}$

Answer (score 2):

There is demonstrably no *general* solution to this class of problems. Argument: we can construct the output as a [Message Authentication Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) (e.g. [HMAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMAC)) of the other inputs, with a random secret fixed key; and what's asked is breaking the MAC.

This class of problems is not modern academic cryptography, which assumes the algorithms are known, only the keys are secret. That's per [Kerckhoffs's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle) (or really, the modern reading of his second principle) .

However, *sometime* it is possible to solve such problem:

- When the program that produces the output is available, it can be reverse-engineered¹ (de-compiled, or/and observed running in a debugger). That's often how software copy-protection is broken.
- When the device that produces the output is available, telltale signs of what it does internally might leak and allow a [side-channel attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-channel_attack).
- For some classes of algorithms, including CRCs, there are general attack techniques given a number of input/output pairs.

---

¹ If the algorithm is simple enough. It is possible to make a program that implements a function in essentially the shortest possible way, by using it's own code as key. This program *is* the canonical form of the algorithm. It can sill be ported to another CPU, with enough memory.

Comment: If it's a simple algorithm you might be able to deduce input-output relationships, but that's more of an attack on some crappy piece of code someone figured might qualify as "crypto"